# How to isolate networks with a Mikrotik router?

Tags: firewall, iptables, mikrotik-routeros

I recently got a [Mikrotik router](http://routerboard.com/RB2011UiAS-2HnD-IN) for my network, and I want to create 3 networks that are isolated from each other but all having internet access:

1. The "main" network for PCs, etc.
2. A network for home automation devices/appliances.  I do not want these hosts to be able to access the other networks, but I want some specific hosts on the main network to be able to access specific hosts on this network.
3. A guest network for visitors.  I want hosts on this network to only have internet access, and be completely isolated from the other networks.

I've been able to setup these three networks using bridges by following [these instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20130416000704/http://networkingforintegrators.com/2013/01/how-to-run-multiple-networks-from-a-mikrotik/) and also mimicking the default configuration that came with the router.

It sound like I  now need to define firewall rules to block the traffic between the bridges, and it's here where I need a little help.  My understanding is that the Mikrotik firewall software is based on Linux iptables.

1. There seems like there's two places to do this: the main firewall configuration in `/ip firewall filter`, and a bridge-specific section in `/interface bridge filter`.  Which one would be best to use?  What are the pros and cons of each?
2. I'm experimenting with the bridge filters, but all my rules have a little [traffic bar icon](http://www.allpark.co.uk/user/products/large/Red_White_Bar_Large.jpg) next to them, which doesn't look good to me.  I can't find any explanation of what the icon means.
3. How should I setup the rules?  Would it be more manageable create a bunch of separate chains for each bridge?  If so, how should the chains be organized?
4. It sounds like I need to define `forward` rules for this.  Are there any `input` or `output` rules that I would need as well?
5. I should have the rules match on the bridges/interfaces (i.e. in-bridge, out-bridge, WAN interface, etc.), correct? E.g. to block packets from the main network to the home automation network, I would need a rules that's something like in-bridge=main out-bridge=home_automation action=DROP, correct?

Comment: If you have an alternate approach, feel free to suggest it.  These networks are all setup on a single router (they have different switchports/SSIDs assigned to them), but it appears the router will automatically route between all the networks it has routes to.

Comment: The above comment was in response to a now-deleted comment.

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, Mikrotik devices does  routing automatically between networks. Consider the two networks 10.0.0.1/16 and 192.168.1.0/24, for example. If you want to block traffic between those two, just add two firewall rules

```
ip firewall filter add chain=forward src-address=10.0.0.0/16 dst-address=192.168.1.0/24 action=drop
ip firewall filter add chain=forward src-address=192.168.1.0/24 dst-address=10.0.0.0/16 action=drop
```

so you drop packets in both directions.